# spark dataframe matching nth regex pattern

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scalaz

How can I scan a spark dataframe string column for regex pattern and get nth match (i.e.  USD 200,765.00)? BTW, I tried adding "{3}" at the end of  the pattern and did not work.

I appreciate any hints.

Comment: What do you mean by the _`nth pattern`_, do you have a bunch of regexes ?

Comment: If you have a column you want to extract use the delimiter it uses `^(?:[^,]*,){N-1}([^,]+)`

Comment: If the delimiter is whitespace, something like this for the column `^(?:\S+\s+){N-1}(\S+)` Note if it is a fixed position, you could just substring it.

Comment: Please add some input examples as well as expected output. Right now your question is not very clear.